# Setting Cell type Error

Tags: java, excel

I'm reading an excel file that contains some numeric value using Apache POI and I want to convert then to a string

when I type `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);`  It shows like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnaML.jpg) and I get an `NullPointerException`

Can anyone help me?

```
public void CreateDir() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (getStartAvailablility() == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Choose Where To Save The Files First!!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Working On It Please Wait..");
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getChooseFilepath());
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {

                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                try {
                    if (cell != null) {
                        File dir = new File(getWorkSpacePath() + "\\" + cell);
                        // if the directory does not exist, create it
                        //System.out.println(Files.list(Paths.get(getWorkSpacePath()+dir.getName())).count());

                        if (!dir.exists()) {
                            try {
                                dir.mkdir();

                            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                                se.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

`

Comment: you are using deprecated things.... why?

Comment: Sorry I didnt undertsant

Comment: are you sure your cell is not null?

Comment: can you add some code to the question?

Comment: If your .xlsx file contains at least 2 rows and 3 columns the NPE is not because of `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);`

Comment: why are you creating a folder with such path `path\java.lang.Object@15db9742` ? Is that intentionally or you want to create a folder with cell value name `cell.getStringCellValue()` ?

Comment: Yes I want to create a folder with the cell value name

Comment: Try this `new File(getWorkSpacePath() + "\\" + cell.getStringCellValue()); `

Comment: The thing is some of the cells are number and when They got created decimal point were added to them for example if the cell value is 0 the folder name become 0.0 and I dont want that this why Im trying to convert the cell to String to make it 0 instead of 0.0

Comment: Thanks a lot Ill try it now

Comment: I tried It and but this Error Occurs java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell

Comment: cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); this line make everything perfect but at the end it shows null pointer exception what I think is that It works fine till it counters an empty cell, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: in which line the code throws NPE?

Comment: on this line cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

Comment: `row.getCell(n)` returns null if the cell does not exist in the row (something not directly visible in the excel file)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CreateDir() throws IOException {
    //....

    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(getCellValue(cell)); 
    //Value of cell is converted to String. 
    //Setting a cell to a string value sets the cell type to a String.

    //....
}

//helper method that grabs cell value regardless of type, and converts to String
public static String getCellValue(Cell cell){
    String a = "";
    int b;
    double c;
    if(cell != null){
        int type = cell.getCellType();
        switch (type) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                c = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                if(c%1 == 0){
                    b = (int) c;
                    a = b + "";
                }else{
                    a = c + "";
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                a = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                a = cell.getCellFormula() + "";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                a = "";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                a = cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```